# How do i use dependency injection with generic dbset<T>

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, interface, .net-core

I have an interface i wish to use to carry out a validity check, as simple as pass an id into a method and it should return true or false whether that entity exist. I do not want to have this implementation for each one of my repositories so i created a seperate interface `IValidityCheck<T> where T: DbSet<T>` as shown below.

```
public interface IValidityCheck<T> where T: DbSet<T>
{
    bool IsValid(Guid id, T entitySet);
}
```

now in my .net core application, i am trying to add the dependency for this. I have something like.

```
services.AddTransient<IValidityCheck<DbSet<School>>, ValidityCheck<DbSet<School>>>();
```

but i get an error like

> The type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet'
>   cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'IValidityCheck'.  There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet'
>   to 
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet>'

I know changing it to constraint to `where T: class` will make it easier but i want the constraint to be specific to `DbSet`

Comment: How can T be a DbSet<T>? I think you need another generic variable

Comment: Your definition is like an infinite recursive loop. How about `public interface IValidityCheck<T, I> where T: DbSet<I>` and `services.AddTransient<IValidityCheck<DbSet<School>, School>, ValidityCheck<DbSet<School>,School>>();`

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options:

1) You may need one more parameter. Like this:

```
public interface IValidityCheck<T, I> where T: DbSet<I>
```

and use it like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IValidityCheck<DbSet<School>, School>, ValidityCheck<DbSet<School>,School>>();
```

2) Another possibility is you could abstract that DbSet away by introducing one more interface:

```
public interface IValidityCheckBase<T> where T: class
{
    bool IsValid(Guid id, T entitySet);
}

public interface IValidityCheck<T> : IValidityCheckBase<DbSet<T>>
{

}
```

Your example generic implementation:

```
 public class ValidityCheck<T> : IValidityCheck<T>
    {
        public bool IsValid(Guid id, DbSet<T> entitySet)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then it should work even **without** declaring DbSet in your generic type usage because you want to force it to be DbSet anyway, this should be more concise:

```
services.AddTransient<IValidityCheck<School>, ValidityCheck<School>>();
```

In this [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gLenFx), I use `List<T>` instead, but it should be similar. I personally like the 2) option. You see that code compiles just fine in the demo.